# Let $f(x) = \frac{7x+6}5$ and g$(x) = 10x+10$. Determine $(-10f+5g)(-4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

I would like to know how to approach this in the first place. I would think just subbing the function equations in for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would work, but all the answers are integers with no x in them. Any help would be greatly appreciated

> Let $f(x) = \frac{7x+6}5$ and $g(x) = 10x+10$.
>
> Determine $(-10f+5g)(-4)$

Comment: Word to the wise: Writing $(-4)f$ or $-4f(x)$ or $(-4)f(x)$ is very different from writing $f(-4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difficulty that you face is how to evaluate $(-10f+5g)$

Note that $$(-10f+5g)(x)=-10f(x)+5g(x)$$

Evaluate it by letting $x= - 4$.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it doesn't mean multiply the entire thing by -4, instead let x=-4?

Comment: Right, @ValidBass. Just like $f(-4)$ means to evaluate $f(x)$ for $x=-4$.

Comment: Yup, evaluate at that value.

Answer (score 0):

$$(-10f+5g)(-4)=-10\cdot\frac{7(-4)+6}{5}+5\cdot(10(-4)+10)=-106$$

Comment: Thanks so much. So that -4 that it appears to be multiplied by is the value I use for x?

Comment: @Valid Bass It's a substitution $x=-4$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.

Comment: @Valid Bass You are welcome!